# Failure to create a network object from edge list with RSiena Test

Tags: r, network-analysis

I am trying to use RSiena Test's sienaDataCreateFromSession() function to create a network object from an edge list. However, the available documentation for the function does not provide any instruction how to do so: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RSiena/versions/1.1-232/topics/sienaDataCreateFromSession

I would be grateful for any advice and example how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

While the function mentioned, `sienaDataCreateFromSession()`, is still available in the `{RSienaTest}` package from R-Forge, it is effectively obsolete.

Users are recommended to instead import data into their R session in whatever form they have it in, and then wrangle it into the correct shape for `sienaDataCreate()` and `sienaDependent()` as outlined in the manual.

If there is continued need for additional helper functions in the main package, please raise this as an issue on the [RSiena Github page](https://github.com/snlab-nl/rsiena).